# Branching Process; understanding theorem proof

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, martingales

Now I'm reading Durrett's probability book and having trouble understanding the proof of one of the theorems related to Branching Process. (Theorem 5.3.8.)

Let $\xi_i^m,$ $\, i,n\geq 1$ be i.i.d. nonnegative integer-valued random variables and let $Z_n$ be a Galton-Watson process w.r.t. $\xi_i^m$.

Suppose $\mu = \mathbb{E}\xi_i^m = 1$ and $\mathbb{P}(\xi_i^m = 1) < 1$.

*Then $\mathbb{P}(Z_n = k ~~ \text{for all} ~~ n \geq N) = 0$ for $k > 0$ and for any positive integer $N$.*

**The last sentence is what I want to understand.**

Any help will be appreicated!

Answer (score 0):

**Sketch:**
Notice that $\mathbb{P} ( Z_{n+1} =k       |Z_n=k   ) \leq 1-\mathbb{P}(\xi^m_i=0)^k<1$.

From the Markov's Propetry we see
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(Z_n = k ~~ \text{for all} ~~ M \geq n \geq N) &= \mathbb{P}(Z_N=k) \mathbb{P} ( Z_{N+1} =k | Z_N=k      )\cdots\mathbb{P}(Z_M=k|Z_{M-1} =k)\\
&\leq\mathbb{P}(Z_N=k) ( 1-\mathbb{P}(\xi^m_i=0)^k)^{(M-N-2)}
\end{align} 
Now taking $M\rightarrow \infty$ yields the result.

Answer (score 0):

I think @clark argument is correct but there are still a few details missing. Following his argument, by the Markov property,

$$
\begin{align*}
    \mathbb{P}(Z _n = k \text{ for all } n \geq N)
    &= \mathbb{P}(Z _n = k , \; Z _{n+1} = k, \; Z _{n+2} = k, \dots) \\
    &= \mathbb{P}(Z _n = k) \cdot \mathbb{P}(Z _{n+1} = k | Z_n = k)
    \cdot \mathbb{P}(Z _{n+2} = k | Z_n = k, \; Z_{n+1} = k) \cdots \\ 
    &= \mathbb{P}(Z _n = k) \cdot \mathbb{P}(Z _{n+1} = k | Z_n = k)
    \cdot \mathbb{P}(Z _{n+2} = k | Z_{n+1} = k) \cdots
\end{align*}
$$

Inituitively, $Z_n$ has the Markov property since
$$
    Z_n = 
    \begin{cases}
    \xi_1 ^{n} + \cdots + \xi_{Z_{n-1}} ^{n} &\text{if } Z _{n-1} > 0 \\ 
    0 &\text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
$$
depends only on $Z _{n-1}$.

In particular, at a certain $i$,
$$
    \mathbb{P}(Z _{i+1} = k | Z_i = k)
    = \mathbb{P}(\xi_1 ^{i+1} + \cdots + \xi_{Z_{i}} ^{i+1} | Z_i = k)
    = \mathbb{P} \left(
        \sum _{j = 1} ^k \xi ^{i+1} _j = k    
    \right).
    \tag{*}
$$

We want to show that the probability on the right is less than $1$. From the condition that $\mathbb{E} \xi ^m _j = \mu = 1$,
$$
\begin{gather*}
    \mathbb{P}(\xi _j ^m = 1) 
    + \sum _{k = 2} ^\infty k \mathbb{P}(\xi ^m _j = k) 
    = \mathbb{E} \xi ^m _j = 1 \\ 
    \implies 
    \sum _{k = 2} ^\infty k \mathbb{P}(\xi ^m _j = k) 
    = 1 - \mathbb{P}(\xi _j ^m = 1) > 0 \\  
    \implies \mathbb{P}(\xi ^m _j = k) > 0 \quad \text{for some } k
\end{gather*}
$$
as otherwise, if $\mathbb{P}(\xi ^m _j = k)$ for all $k$ then the sum will be $0$. Furthermore, since $\xi ^m _j$ only take nonnegative integer values,
$$
\begin{gather*}
    \mathbb{P}(\xi _j ^m = 0)  + \mathbb{P}(\xi _j ^m = 1) 
    + \sum _{k = 2} ^\infty \mathbb{P}(\xi ^m _j = k) = 1 \\ 
    \implies 
    \mathbb{P}(\xi _j ^m = 0) 
    + \sum _{k = 2} ^\infty \mathbb{P}(\xi ^m _j = k) 
    = 1 -  \mathbb{P}(\xi _j ^m = 1) \\ 
    \implies 
    \mathbb{P}(\xi _j ^m = 0) 
    + \sum _{k = 2} ^\infty \mathbb{P}(\xi ^m _j = k) 
    = \sum _{k = 2} ^\infty k \mathbb{P}(\xi ^m _j = k)  \\  
    \implies 
    \mathbb{P}(\xi _j ^m = 0) 
    = \sum _{k = 2} ^\infty (k - 1) \mathbb{P}(\xi ^m _j = k).
\end{gather*}
$$
All the summands are nonnegative, and we know there is $k$ which
$\mathbb{P}(\xi ^m _j = k) > 0$. So
$$
    \mathbb{P}(\xi _j ^m = 0) > 0.
$$

Going back to (*), we still do not know this probability, but we know that
$\{ \xi _j ^m = 0 \text{ for } j = 1, \dots , k\}$ is in its complement, so
$$
    \mathbb{P}(Z _{i+1} = k | Z_i = k)
    = \mathbb{P} \left(
        \sum _{j = 1} ^k \xi ^{i+1} _j = k    
    \right)
    \leq 1 - \mathbb{P}(\xi _1 ^m = 0) ^k < 1.
$$

Finally, $\mathbb{P}(Z _n = k \text{ for all } n \geq N)$ is an infinite product of such terms which are less than $1$, so it must be $0$.